# Theme for inner menu item does not work. Joomla 2.5

Tags: templates, joomla

I have a website in Joomla and have created two themes for main-and-inner pages respectively.
When i created inner menu items i assigned them the inner-theme it works fine the first time you navigate to the theme but on the second hit to the page it just shows the home page theme. its really odd.

On my local machine everything works perfectly, this issue only arises when i upload it.

One more thing i am new to Joomla the way i made the template was i used the same home page template and changed the  name attribute in the inner page but kept some of the module name same as in the home page so i could assign the module once and it could work on both templates. inner page differs in size of the banner & has breadcrumb module + 1 more that differentiates it from the home page.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the `Itemid` not propagated properly. The `Itemid` identifies a menu item, from which the settings are read. If the `Itemid` is missing, the settings of the default page (your main page) are used instead.

If you just want to slightly change the appearance of the front page and other pages, you can do that with *one* single template. See the Joomla! online documentation for [how to determine if the user is viewing the front page](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page).